# Is it possible to only encode data coming from the server using jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I've set "autoencode" to true on my jqGrid tables to prevent any XSS attempts on my website. However I only want this to apply to data coming from the server and NOT data being posted from the web app to the server.

Is there a way to make this encoding one-way instead of always being bidirectional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I am answering it right, however this looks like could be a possible approach

[How to alter data received from the server before processing by jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259226/how-to-alter-data-received-from-the-server-before-processing-by-jqgrid)

Comment: I was able to come up with a solution using this strategy, thanks!

It really should be configurable in the framework but I'm glad I was able to get it working.